# Uploaded files missing

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am uploading file in the server location everytime..but after sometime or next day that location is missing from my system.so i am getting error file not found exception always..

Here is my code

```
        String fileName = file.getFileName().trim();
           if(!("").equals(fileName)){  
               long timeStamp = com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getCurrentTimeNanosOrMillis();
                String fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("."));               
                fileName = fileName.substring(0,fileName.lastIndexOf("."));             
                String newFileName = fileName.concat("-").concat(String.valueOf(timeStamp)).concat(fileExtension);
                String foldercreated = folder + "\\" + newFileName;
                dto.setReplyDocName(newFileName);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(foldercreated);
                fos.write(file.getFileData());
                dto.setReplyDocLocation(foldercreated);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();

        }
```

Comment: "location is missing" <-- what does that mean? Give a scenario in which the above code fails. Also, if you use Java 7, please use java.nio.file.*

Comment: What OS? Which folder are you saving to? If it's a temp folder the OS could be periodically clearing it out.

Comment: @NickWilson Yes... in temp folder..E:\PRG\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\

Comment: @fge files are uploaded when try to upload in location...but when i try to retrieve the file the location is mising..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing the uploaded files in a temp directory that Eclipse uses to deploy the webapp. So each time you deploy the webapp, this directory will be cleared.

Uploaded files shouldn't be stored there. Configure an absolute path where the files should be stored (like `c:\uploaded_files`), and store the files in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

To store uploaded files you can create a new folder inside your webapp and then you can use this location as:

```
File file=new File(session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/Your_Location"));
```

Or you can use any absolute location.

Comment: That will cause the problem that the OP is precisely trying to avoid: every redeploy of the webapp will delete the uploaded files. Uplodaded files are data. They have nothing to do with the code of the webapp. And moreover, it won't work if the app is deployed as an unexploded war file.